# Возможно ли ускорить clion и clangd?

Tags: ubuntu, clion

Возможно ли ускорить clion и clangd? Купил хорошее железо, и к моему удивлению, обноружил что clion не начал работать быстрее. Может етсь настройки, чтоб установить больший расход оперативнйо памяти и ядер для самог clion и cland который используется в контексте clion.

Comment: а что такое "хорошее железо"? когда то лет 5 назад на одном форуме нашел упоминания, что человек пишет, что у него 128 гиг памяти и оно все равно работает неважно. Попробуйте другой редактор. Я бы начал с visual studio code, а потом vim/nvim. Там через lsp прикручивается clangd и все отлично работает.

Comment: да, железо хорошее, решение нашел, в настройках clion поставил максимальных хип для самого слиона и clangd, так же исключил лишние директории из индекса(проект является монорепой и в нем много таргетов). работать стало в 10 раз быстрее @KoVadim

Comment: так что такое хорошее железо?

Comment: @KoVadim, 64 гб оперативной памяти, мощный процессор(но тут основную роль игарет память, в моем понимании)

Comment: я понял. 64 гига - это сейчас рядовая машина разработчика. Средняя-средняя. Хочу разочаровать, но похоже у Вас относительно обычное железо.